# Map by density of information per pixel?

Tags: qgis, classification, mapping

I am working with QGIS. I have 6 shp files of the same pixel resolution (1 pixel = 10*10km).

My issue is that I would like to represent them all on one map as such manner that the color varies according to the amount of information each pixel contains.

For example, a certain pixel where only 1 shp would give its information would be lighter than another pixel that would contain te information of 4 sph at the same time. Thus, I would have the seven following classification:

- pixel with 0 info
- pixel with only 1 info
- pixel with 2 infos
  ...
- pixel with all 6 infos

Is this possible?

Screenshot of the data :

[image]

Comment: Shapefiles don't have pixels, those are raster-exclusive. Maybe you could add a screenshot of your data.

Comment: @Erik thanks, I have edited the message. It is based on a pixel grid but you are right it's not proper pixels, just squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possibility.

1. Rasterise each layer to a grid. Menu option:

   ```
   Raster - Conversion - Rasterize
   ```

This will create a grid from a vector (polygon in this case) layer. You can specify the grid spacing, extent, and which attribute in your polygon feature to use as a 'burn-in' value.

The grid will be set to that value (or a constant) whenever a grid node is in your vector polygon.

You can specify what the value of the grid should be if it is not within a polygon feature (nodata value).

Do the same for each vector layer.

2. Sum the grids with the Raster Calculator. Menu:

   ```
   Raster - Raster Calculator
   ```

This is pretty easy. Add the value from each grid to make a sum. If you use values of 1, 2, 4, 8, etc., in your grids, the sum will uniquely identify which layers are active at that point, but you already knew that :-)

3. Colour the sum as required using Layer Styling

That should give you the number of shapes at any given point in the grid.

**- edit -**

When you rasterise in **Raster - Conversion - Rasterize**, *do not set a nodata value*. If there is a zero there, remove it.

[image: 2 overlapping Vector Layers overlaid]

After rasterizing, the layers look like this - Blue means 1:

[image: 2 rasterized vector layers overlaid - Blue means 1]

After summing in the Raster Calculator, the raster output looks like this - Yellow means 1, Blue means 2:

[image: Single Summed Raster - Yellow means 1, Blue means 2]

As you can see, the procedure does what you would expect. When yours looked blank, I suspect it was related to having nodata values. In that case, only overlapping areas would be created.

Another area that is often annoying is in the CRS. Ensure they are identical for all input layers, the output layer, and the project CRS, to rule out misalignment issues (by a million miles)

HTH

Comment: Could you please help me with step 1 by giving some details? I have never done this before and I am struggling. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Sure - I'll edit the answer with more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I have done the first step, but I still do not succeed at step 2. The formula I entered in the calculator is: raster1 + raster2 + ... + raster n - and the result is just a full black raster.

Comment: Did the individual rasters look correct? Are they integer or floating point?

Comment: The rasters look correct individually, the data type is Float32. For each raster, I have 2 colors, either white = 0 (absence) or black = 1 (presence).

Comment: I tried it myself. I created 2 shape layers, then rasterized them. I then combined them with the Raster Calculator. I'll edit the answer bove.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122785/discussion-between-wingnut-and-recology).